# Entity Framework - adding the same entity twice in many-to-many relationships

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, duplicates

Ok. So here is the deal. I have two entities - "Product" and "Parts". The product consists of parts. And parts are reusable in other products. The relation between those entities is many-to-many. And it all works great.

**The problem is** that I cannot add the same part to the same product twice. EF seems to force all the related entities to be unique. Consider the following code:

```
var product = context.Create<Product>();
var part = GetSomePart();

Console.WriteLine(product.Parts.Count); // will output 0

// Add a part
product.Parts.Add(part);
Console.WriteLine(product.Parts.Count); // will output 1

// Add the same part again
product.Parts.Add(part);
Console.WriteLine(product.Parts.Count); // will output 1!
```

So ok, I get the point - avoid duplicates or something. But I need this to be possible. Is there a way to do this (to tell EF to stop enforcing unique values) without creating an additional table? Or is the only way to resolve this is to manually add the intermediate table and handle the many-to-many myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you will have to create another table called "ProductParts" which will have an identity unique key, and which can hold references to both product and part, and they can be multiple too.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will have to go this way unless someone else comes up with a native EF solution (which I doubt).

Comment: This is the only way it is possible, since in many to many, your both keys will form unique key and you wont be able to add it in database anyway. Your combination is unique in many to many with just ids being primary key.

Comment: Jep, I was just thinking if I could tell EF to add this surrogate key itself. But I guess this is not possible. Thanks for your explanation - marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In the second add statement it will not add another object because `part` is already in added state. So you need to create a new object with same properties add it again.

```
product.Parts.Add(new Part{someProperty=part.someProperty ... ect });
```

if you want to reduce code you can use Automapper ( http://automapper.codeplex.com/ )to copy all properties,

```
 product.Parts.Add(Mapper.Map<Part,Part>(part));
```

Comment: The point is to have the same reference added twice. Adding a copied object as not the same. But thanks anyway :)