# Entity Framework - Add an item to a list more than once

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I am creating an Entity Framwork Code First app and am running into a problem when trying to add an entity to a list more than once.

I have the following two classes, which reference each other for a many-to-many relationship.

```
public class Order
{

    public virtual List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

}   

public class OrderItem
{

    public virtual List<Order> Orders{ get; set; }

}
```

This creates a the following three tables in my database:

```
Orders
 - OrderId (PK, int)
```

.

```
OrderItems
 - OrderItemId (PK, int)
```

.

```
OrderOrderItems
 - Order_OrderId (PK,FK,int)
 - OrderItem_OrderItemId (PK,FK,int)
```

In code, I wish to do the following:

```
private void AddOrderItemsTest 
{
    OrderItem orderItem = GetOrderItem(); // gets an existing order item from the DB
    var order = new Order();
    order.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
    order.OrderItems.Add(orderItem); // add the order item to the list a second time
    context.Orders.Add(order);
}
```

When this gets persisted to the database, only a single `orderItem` entity is added to the list. We see in the table OrderOrderItems that OrderItem_OrderItemId is a PK and therefore must be unique. This means that EF has designed the tables in a way that won't allow more than one orderItem of the same type to be added to the list more than once.

Is there a Data Annotation that I can add to tell EF to allow me to add more than one item of the same type to the list?

Comment: This question appears to ask the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191132/entity-framework-adding-the-same-entity-twice-in-many-to-many-relationships  
That question is three years old though, so unless you are certain that nothing has changed between now and then (We are on EF6 now) please do not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: What is purpose of adding same item to collection twice? How you expect that data stored in tables? multiple duplicated rows in *OrderOrderItems* or two distinct records in *OrderItems* and *OrderOrderItems*?

Comment: @Vladimirs If a customer wants to buy two of the same item, then I would add it twice to the list. I'd expect two duplicate rows in `OrderOrderItems` table but I don't really mind how EF implements it!

Comment: doh.. for some stupid reason I didn't even bother to read you first comment (think best to include that info to actual question). I believe that nothing changed as you still need primary key on many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is not correct way of handling item count (of same item) in your order. Do you really want 10000s duplicated entries loaded into your `OrderItems` collection? I guess not.

You will need different primary key on `OrderOrderItems` table, hence suggest to introduce new entity that will contain `OrderItem` amount per `Order`:

```
public class OrderItemDetails
{
    public int OrderItemDetailsId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int Amount{ get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderItem OrderItem { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public virtual List<OrderItemDetails> OrderItemDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public virtual List<OrderItemDetails> OrderItemDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And if you not happy with introducing `Amount` and still want to have duplicated entries per each item instance that will be absolutely fine because primary key of your many to many relation will be not combination of `OrderId` and `OrderItemId` but `OrderItemDetailsId`.

Comment: You are spot on - that's a much better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: This also sets up a nice place to store a 'frozen' copy of the OrderItem - to manage changes in price etc down the road.